# How can I make a Unity Raycast go out in a random direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a shotgun in unity with raycasts that has random pellet spread. How can I make a Raycast go out in a random direction within a specified radius (eg. 20 degrees)?

this is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (((GunInfo)itemInfo).bullets); i++){
    Ray ray = cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f));
    ray.origin = cam.transform.position;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
    {
        hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<IDamageable>()?.TakeDamage(((GunInfo)itemInfo).damage); //ignore this
        PV.RPC("RPC_Shoot", RpcTarget.All, hit.point, hit.normal); //ignore this
    }
}
```

I honestly am not super experienced with raycasts so I haven't been able to figure anything out yet. I also haven't found any other solutions that make sense to me in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly what you were asking for. How I creatively got around this same conundrum was by creating a bullet gameobject with a script attached that fired a ray straight out. I then give that bullet a random rotation.

```
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public float deviation

for (int i = 0; i < (((GunInfo)itemInfo).bullets); i++)
{
    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, cam.transform.position, cam.transform.rotation); 

    float xDeviation = Random.Range(-deviation, deviation);
    float yDeviation = Random.Range(-deviation, deviation);
    float zDeviation = Random.Range(-deviation, deviation);

    bullet.transform.Rotate(xDeviation, yDeviation, zDeviation);

    bullet.SetActive(true);
}
```

And then because all my bullets fire their rays on awake and start inactive, I set them active and the bullet script handles the rest.